# Declaración de un constructor en una clase PHP

Tags: php, pdo, poo

Buenos días amigos,

Estoy aprendiendo a programar orientado a objetos con PHP y me surgen algunas dudas:
- ¿es necesario declarar el método constructor en todas las clases?
- si yo voy a declarar las propiedades de un objeto es necesario que las declare al principio de la clase o las puedo ir declarando después cuando cree el objeto, es decir, tener algo como esto en el código:

```
 class Ejemplo{
(y tener la clase sin propiedades declaradas ni método constructor)
}

$Ejemeplo1= new Ejemplo();
$Ejemplo1->propiedad=$propiedad;
```

Muchas gracias amigos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No es necesario declarar el constructor de la clase, ya que implícitamente tu objeto hereda de `stdClass`, y esta clase ya tiene un constructor.

El código `$Ejemplo1->propiedad` en principio provocaría un error al intentar acceder a una propiedad no declarada, de forma pública. Aun así, podrías hacerlo si defines los métodos mágicos [__set](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) y [__get](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get). No obstante, te recomiendo que declares las propiedades de tus clases, no querrás que otra persona que tenga que lidiar con tu código tenga que volverse loca pensando de dónde sale tal cosa o tal otra. Es una buena práctica.

Por último, sí podrías hacer una asignación implícita dentro del constructor o los métodos de tu clase.

```
<?php 
class Ejemplo 
{

    public function algo()
    {
        $this->propiedad = 'algo';
    }

}

$ejemplo = new Ejemplo();
$ejemplo->algo();
echo $ejemplo->propiedad;
```